# A/C blows cold air for few seconds, then warm air, then cold

Tags: honda, ac, civic

As said in title, our Honda Civic 1.8 2009 petrol model A/C doesn't work properly.

When A/C is on it may & may not give cold air. Suddenly after some time it starts working and blowing cold air. After few seconds/minute it stops working and blowing warm air. Again after few minutes it starts working and stops abruptly. This kind of sequence goes on and on.

We are seeking a right advice for getting it repaired and functioning properly at reasonable cost.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you hear a hissing sound from under the footwell when it's cooling? Also, please observe the compressor clutch, does it still turn while it's acting up?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the system needs a recharge. Since it's sporadic like you are talking about, it seems one of the pressures the system reads for is out of bounds (low in this case) during operation, which shuts the system down (the compressor is turned off) which causes the cold air not to flow. As soon as the system equalizes and pressures go up on the low side, the system cuts back in and it will cool for a little bit until things get out of bounds again.

If this is what the issue is, it doesn't mean your system has a real issue (other than needing more refrigerant). If you don't use your A/C system regularly, it can lose refrigerant past the seals ... just a fact of life. It should just need the recharge and with regular usage be good to go.

I'm not sure if you have the means in your location to recharge this on your own, but would suggest if you have never messed with an A/C system before to take it somewhere and have them do it for you. Taking it to a place which specializes in A/C repairs is going to be your best bet.